# JQUERY Toggle Child UL

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<li class="helpClickable">What are the Terms of Service &amp; Privacy Policy?</li>
<ul class="helpToggleAll"> 
  <li class="helpContent"><span class="helpText">The Terms of Service are the Terms you agreed to when Creating an Account on this or any of the Gone Global Dating Network Sites.</span></li>
  <li class="helpContent"><span class="helpText">The Privacy Policy is the Policy that Governs usage of your Personal Information stored in this Website and in the Gone Global Dating Network.</span></li>
  <li class="helpContent"><span class="helpText">Click either link to re-read the document again - <a href="includes/legal/terms-of-use.php" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> &amp; <a href="includes/legal/privacy-policy.php" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>.</span></li>
  <li class="helpContent"><span class="helpText">If you do not Agree with any part of either of these Documents then cease using this Website and the Gone Global Dating Network Imediendly.</span></li>      
</ul>
```

I need to toggle() the 'helpToggleAll' Class when the 'helpClickable' class is clicked.
I've been testing with the following code without success.

```
 var helpClickable = $('li.helpClickable');
   helpClickable.click(function() {
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
   });
```

What would be the best way to toggle() the child ?

thx

Comment: As noted, the `ul.helpToggleAll` is not a child of an `li`. So, assuming that `li` elements *are* valid children of the parent `ol` or `ul` this makes your mark-up invalid. The ***only*** valid child of a `ul` or `ol` is an `li` element. No others. Wrap the `ul.helpToggleAll` in an `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML should be

```
<li class="helpClickable">What are the Terms of Service &amp; Privacy Policy?
  <ul> 
    <li>The Terms of Service are the Terms you agreed to when Creating an Account on this or any of the Gone Global Dating Network Sites.</li>
    <li>The Privacy Policy is the Policy that Governs usage of your Personal Information stored in this Website and in the Gone Global Dating Network.</li>
    <li>Click either link to re-read the document again - <a href="includes/legal/terms-of-use.php" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> &amp; <a href="includes/legal/privacy-policy.php" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>.</li>
    <li>If you do not Agree with any part of either of these Documents then cease using this Website and the Gone Global Dating Network Imediendly.</li>      
  </ul>
</li>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('li.helpClickable').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

And CSS:

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Your `<span class="helpText">` and `class="helpContent"` are completely redundant, you can handle all of this in CSS:

```
.helpClickable ul { /* styles for the UL */ }
.helpClickable ul li { /* styles for the text */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a child.  You should search for the ul, or use siblings.

```
var helpClickable = $('li.helpClickable');
helpClickable.click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul.helpToggleAll').toggle();
});
```

or

```
var helpClickable = $('li.helpClickable');
helpClickable.click(function() {
    $('ul.helpToggleAll').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.helpToggleAll` isn't a child. It's a sibling:

```
$('.helpClickable').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.helpToggleAll').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not their child.  Try this out:

```
$('.helpClickable').click(function(){
    $('.helpToggleAll').toggle();
});
```